# Initialization required for public static final but not for public final

Tags: java, static, initialization, final

I have three constant floats, whose values I want to be assigned to in the constructor of the class.

I declare all three constants before the constructor. As an experiment, I set different modifiers to each:

```
public static float defaultdim;
public static final float maxdim;
public final float mindim;
```

My IDE, Eclipse, detects an error for the second constant, maxdim, namely:

> the blank final field maxdim may not have been initialized

What puzzles me is not why the error appears but why the error doesn't appear in the case of mindim, which is also final, considering the error message is connected to the fact that the variable is final. In other words, the error is there because a final variable is not initialized during declaration. Both variables are final and both are not initialized, but the error appears in only one case.

The two variables differ by the modifier static, which suggests that would be the cause of the error. However, I do not see why this would be the case since no error appears in the case of defaultdim, which is only static, not final and the error itself does not refer to the modifier static. Could anyone explain the reason behind it to me?

Comment: Can you show the code in the constructors of this class?

Comment: Are you bugging me? a `static final` var must have a initial value with its declaration, so you get this error.

Comment: "I have three constant floats, whose values I want to be assigned to in the constructor of the class." This is a contradiction. Do you know what a constant is?

Comment: @xehpuk That statement is not a contradiction - it depicts what I want and since this is what I want, it is true and not contradictory. Now, the reason I want to assign a value to them in the constructor is because they are based on the arguments passed to the constructor. I also recognize they should be final because from the assignment onwards their values will not not change (yes I do know what constant means) and I also do recognize they should be static - since they will be shared by all instances of the given class. I would be highly grateful if you could tell me how to solve this issue.

Comment: If you assign them in the constructor, then they aren't constants.

Comment: Well apparently the mindim field (final but not static) can be declared outside the constructor and then initialized within the constructor. But what I'm interested in , is how to overcome the described issue. The given float should both be final and static and should be initialized in the constructor because its value, which doesnt change at all from the assignment onwards and is shared by all instances, depends on the parameters given to the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`public static float defaultdim;`**

`static` field which will be initialized with *default* value `0.0F` in case of `float` if you have not specified the value explicitly. (*i.e.* In case of `int` it will have `0`) Moreover, it's *not* `final`.

Next both declarations are considered as *blank* final fields declarations which lacks the *initializer*.

---

**`public static final float maxdim;`**

Every `final` field must only be assigned once and atleast before making use of it. `static` variables initialized when class is loaded and due to it's `final` it must have value while the `class` is being loaded and yet you receive the error in case of `static final` (*constant*).

---

**`public final float mindim;`**

In above case you have not initialized it anywhere in code, what compiler thinks you will not have this variable initialized anymore in future as well. You must initialize it before making any use of it. You can avoid *compile* time error in this case by initializing it in constructor.

```
public Test(float mindim) {
    this.mindim = mindim;
}
```

By doing this you have assured compiler that `mindim` will be initialized before being used anywhere in code, *note* that it's not `static` and it will have different copy for each `Object` you create for your class.

> But what if I need to assign a value to a static final field based on
>   an argument passed to the constructor of the class?

No. `static final` field is `Class` related thing while *constructor* is  `Object` thing. Your constant should be initialized when `class` is loaded while your constructor will be called when you create `Object` of class with `new`. There is no meaning of initializing constant in constructor. If it can vary with every Object than it's definitely not a *constant*. Yes you can keep your field only `final` and assign value based on constructor parameter because that way it will have `final` value for each `Object`.

Comment: technically, all fields are first initialized to default values. a field `final int x=1;` actually involves 2 writes. the first write (x=0) can be observable.

Comment: That explains it very well, thanks. But what if I need to assign a value to a static final field based on an argument passed to the constructor of the class? In my program, all objects created from the given class will have the same defaultdim field and that defaultdim does not change, which means the modifiers should be static and final. However, that defaultdim can only be determined from the parameter given to the constructor. What to do then?

Comment: @bayou.io Excluding constant variables, which never have a default value.

Comment: @xehpuk - well, the spec is worded such that all fields, including constant variables, are set to default values first. However, for constant static variables, the class initialization process guarantees that the default values are [not observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2)  by anybody. Practically speaking, we can say they don't really have default values; and JVM does not need to zero the fields first.

Comment: @xehpuk - On the other hand, constant *instance* variable is a different story; its default value can be observed. Of course, a constant instance variable makes no sense anyway; it ought to be static.

Answer (score 0):

Because non static variables on start are null